# Is IIS7 migration a piece of cake

Tags: iis-7, migration

I wish to migrate a website to windows 2008 platform, is there any obvious pitfalls i should be aware of?

code base is c# 3.5,asp.net with ms ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I googled a bit and found this link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2008/09/04/iis6-to-iis7-migration-tips-tricks.aspx

Biggest Issue i find is that 3rd party components needs to have 64bit version ready to get most of benefits.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any experience with a migrated application not working properly. I've only done a few, but we've tested a number here at work, and they all run great under IIS7.

The only gotcha is that the .NET "Managed Pipeline Mode" is set to "Integrated" by default, which caused problems in some of our applications. Either setting it to "Classic" on your app pool, or switching your application to use the "Classic .NET" app pool should resolve the problem. For some more information about the new pipeine, [read about it here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/244/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis7-integrated-pipeline/).

Oh - and +1 on the wacked-out interface. I want my old IIS6 interface back!

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the wacked user interface put you off (but it will drive you dilly)

Comment: I love the new UI, its great, lots of stuff there where you'd have to fire up Metaedit or start tweaking the Metabase.xml directly in IIS6.

Comment: It's just not great for the simple tasks that You want to do easily and quickly. For example, if you want to change the default directory of an existing site you have to walk the entire directory tree - it doesn't 'remember' the existing directory.